# doInBackground doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, pdf, swingworker

I have created a small BackGroundWorker for testing a pdf file. Everything works fine until the code catches the path for the pdf file. I really don't know why it isn't working -.- I also don't get any error messages in the console from eclipse. Do you know what is exactly my problem?

```
public class SwingWorkerDemo {
    static JButton pressMe;
    static JPanel buttonPanel;
    static String text;
    protected static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(25, 45);

    public SwingWorkerDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        pressMe= new JButton("Drück mich");
        buttonPanel.add(pressMe);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pressMe.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    runWorker();
                } catch (PDFDocumentException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        public MyTask() throws PDFDocumentException {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            frame.add(textArea);
            frame.pack();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            File inputFiles = new File("C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\pdf\\Name_der_testenden.pdf");
            PDFDocument pdf = new PDFDocument(inputFiles);

            textArea.setText("content errors:" + "\n");
            for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo < pdf.getPages(); pageNo++) {
                try {
                    PCProperty content = pdf.getContent(pageNo, ContentCollationOptions.NONE);

                    if (content == null) {
                       textArea.setText("no content on page " + pageNo + "\n");
                    }

                } catch (PDFDocumentException exception) {
                    textArea.setText("failed to read content on page " + pageNo + "\n");
               }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

 public static void runWorker() throws PDFDocumentException {

        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PDFDocumentException {
        new SwingWorkerDemo();
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to only to read your file in "doInBackground". In this method you should not access any swing component.

Comment: Here `buttonPanel.add(drückMich);` what is that **drückMich** ? I can not see it anywhere else. You want `buttonPanel.add(pressMe);` don't you?

Comment: textArea.setText("no content on page " + pageNo + "\n"); should be in done, otherwise you have to use process/publish or setProcess, really time to read API, resp. Oracle tutorial about SwingWorker (hint whatever from doInBackground never will be notified EDT, is about WorkerThread, more info in Oracle tutorial EventDispatchThread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert but I changed a little your code. First of all I created the window for the worker before calling `execute()`, I pass the `textArea` through the constructor to the task and there I use the `process()` method to update it.

Here is the code, note: I just used some strings with `Thread.sleep()` to imitate the progress.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkerDemo 
{
    static JButton pressMe;
    static JPanel buttonPanel;
    static String text;
    protected static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(25, 45);

    public SwingWorkerDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
        frame.setVisible(true);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        pressMe= new JButton("Drück mich");
        buttonPanel.add(pressMe);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pressMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Worker Frame");
                frame.setVisible(true);

                frame.add(textArea);
                frame.pack();

                MyTask task = new MyTask(textArea);
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    static class MyTask extends SwingWorker<String, String> 
    {
        private JTextArea innerTextArea;

        public MyTask(JTextArea innerTextArea)
        {
            this.innerTextArea = innerTextArea;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception 
        {
            publish("First message:" + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            publish(" no content on page 2:" + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            publish(" no content on page 4:" + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            publish(" no content on page 5" + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            return "reading done";
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks)
        {
            innerTextArea.append(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void done() 
        {
            try 
            {
               innerTextArea.append(get());
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace(System.err);
               System.out.println("error");
            }
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SwingWorkerDemo();
    }
}
```

For more check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) of the `SwingWorker`.